# Additional HipChat Heroku Deploy Hook Options

Tags: git, heroku, hook

I was wondering how to display the commit message and committing user for a HipChat bot commit to a deployment hook for Heroku.  I know this is the basic setup:

```
heroku addons:add deployhooks:hipchat \
    --auth_token=my_auth_token \
    --room="My Company's Room"
```

Would the new Heroku command would probably be something like:

```
heroku addons:add deployhooks:hipchat \
    --auth_token=my_auth_token \
    --room="My Company's Room"
    --user=<<user goes here>>
    --message=<<commit message goes here>>
```

Long story short, when the HipChat bot is updated, how can I send the commit message to the room, and show which user made the commit?  I also know I'm not "adding" the add-on.  What should I change "add" to?

Answer (score 1):

You should have a [look at Heroku's docs on customising the message](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploy-hooks#customizing-messages).

You have the following variables available for customising the message:

```
app:       the app name
user:      email of the user deploying the app
url:       the app URL (http://myapp.heroku.com or http://mydomain.com if you have custom domains enabled)
head:      short identifier of the latest commit (first seven bytes of the SHA1 git object name)
head_long: full identifier of the latest commit
git_log:   log of commits between this deploy and the last
```

You add these to the message, for example, `{{head_log}}`.

You will need to either remove the addon and add it again using the `heroku` command line client, or you can edit the message through Heroku's web interface.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, but I'm not sure how to make the "message" portion of the addon dynamic, and have it show the associated commit message.

Comment: I think I do understand, but I've updated my answer. I think you need `head_long`.